# Cast DVD's from computer to tv

Tags: chromecast

Does anyone know a way to cast DVD's to chromecast from a computer?  I currently use my computer as a dvd player and I would really like to avoid hooking my computer directly to the TV.

**Edit**:  I've found a work around for the DVD's I own.  I currently back up my DVD's using [Shrink DVD](http://www.filehippo.com/download_dvdshrink/) to network storage as ISO files, then use the Windows 8.1 mounting option to mount it to a virtual drive and play the movie on vlc.  So to make it work one more step in the process is needed.  I found a great converter [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).  So, if I convert the movies to mkv file format, it's just a matter of clicking and dragging the movie into the chrome browser and casting the tab.

This is feasible for the DVD's I own but if I rent a DVD I can't legally create a copy like that nor is the time required to convert the movies less than what is required to just plug the computer into the TV.

Comment: What operating system do you have on the computer?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well renting from Google play is what I do now.  DVD's are outdated anyways.